# Get Index of the search array with .all() and any()

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have list of arrays and i am using .all() and .any() to check if the array im searching is in the list of arrays.

```
t = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6] , [7,8,9], [10, 11, 12]])

t2 = np.array([1,2,3])

print((t == t2).all(1))
outpu:> [ True False False False]
```

here i can check if t2 is in t

```
print((t == t2).all(1).any())
outpu:> True
```

My question is can i get on what index in t that t2 exist with .all and .any method?

Comment: Perhaps you want `np.flatnonzero((t == t2).all(1))`

Comment: We could use `in` to check `print(t in t2) #output True`

Comment: Thanks a lot @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ. Thats what im looking for. :D you can add that as answer ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for either `np.flatnonzero` or `np.where`.

```
>>> np.flatnonzero((t == t2).all(1))
```

Or,

```
>>> np.where((t == t2).all(1))[0]
```

```
array([0])
```